# debian dependencies for gem gosu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, debian, libgosu

I'm trying to

```
gem install gosu
```

but I'm getting a lot of compiler messages about missing header files, including sndfile.h.  Is there a list of debian packages that are needed to compile the gosu gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Linux

build-essential freeglut3-dev libfreeimage-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libopenal-dev libpango1.0-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsndfile-dev libxinerama-dev

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue whilst installing on OS X 10.9.4 although am not sure the version has much to do with it, but ruby version is **ruby-2.1.2**

To resolve this, I installed these additional dependencies for Gosu which fixed the problem:

```
brew install sdl2 libogg libvorbis
```

Then run **gem install gosu** as usual.